# Get recipes which don't include X ingredients

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have tree tables:

recipes:

```
id | title | ....
```

recipe_ingredients:

```
recipe_id | ingredient_id
```

ingredients:

```
id | ingredient
```

Each recipe has n of ingredients associated to it.

I wrote a query which gets recipe id, ingredients match count, total number of ingredients for that recipe by ingredient IDs:

```
SELECT recipes.id, recipes.title, ing_match_count,
    (
    SELECT count(id)
    FROM recipe_ingredients as ri
    WHERE ri.recipe_id = recipes.id
    ) as recipe_ing_count
FROM recipes
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT recipe_id, ingredients_id, COUNT(*) AS ing_match_count
    FROM recipe_ingredients
    WHERE ingredients_id IN (19, 25, 30, 40)
    GROUP BY recipe_id
) AS ri
ON recipes.id = ri.recipe_id
ORDER BY ing_match_count DESC
```

The problem is, I'am unable to exclude recipes using other ingredient IDs. The query above search for recipes which have 19, 25, 30, 40 ingredient IDs. But I want to exclude recipes for example which have 22, 23 ingredients as well.

So if recipe has 19 and 22 ingredient id, it won't be displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a fan of using `group by` with the conditions in the `having` clause for these types of queries.  I find that this is the most flexible appraoch.

```
SELECT r.id, r.title,
       SUM(ingredients_id IN (19, 25, 30, 40)) as ing_match_count,
       COUNT(*) as recipe_ing_count
FROM recipes r JOIN
     recipe_ingredients  ri
     ON ri.recipe_id = recipes.id
GROUP BY r.id, r.title
HAVING ing_match_count > 0 AND
       SUM(ingredients_id in (22, 23)) = 0;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `THEN` be `AS`?

Comment: `recipe_ing_count` is missing

Comment: @ChrisWesseling . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  A simple `count(*)` suffices because there is no `where` clause filtering the ingredients.

Comment: Most flexible, yes. But with huge datasets this approach is performing really bad, because a cross product of `ALL` rows is built based and grouping is done for `ALL` rows in the resulting set. Note: the `HAVING` close is evaluated last, after building all SETs and after all grouping done. You can gain MUCH better performance with a more complex query.

Comment: @Kaii . . . This performs bad on MySQL because MySQL doesn't do a good job implementing good aggregation algorithms.  Alas.  Performance is much less of an issue on other databases.  And, if your version of MySQL is using indexes for `group by`, then you can speed the query with indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff agreed. But i thought readers should know that albeit this being the most flexible and self-evident solution, it is not the best solution (performance-wise) for MySQL. Still, with modern MySQL and `GROUP BY` aided with an INDEX, the engine still has to scan `ALL` rows of the resulting set to satisfy `HAVING`. It will perform much better when you add a `WHERE` clause that filters for recipes actually including any of the desired ingredients first. (given the ingredients are indexed correctly, of course)